# UILabel - Long press gesture for menu item of UIMenuController

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uimenucontroller, long-press

I need to handle long press action/gesture on UILable, in an entire app, and it should show a menu like this, with custom menu options:

[image]

As per apple interface guideline a text field, a text view, a web view, and an image view can only enable this menu.

Is it feasible to add such action in UILabel for the entire app and open custom menu by adding own menu options, with existing?

Comment: no your  need to custom to achieve this one

Comment: Not necessarily...I'm working on an answer with a code example for you now.

Comment: @DonovanKing nice to see you here for my help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a `UILabel` subclass that handles long pressing to show the `UIMenuController`. You can also add more actions the the menu controller for use case.

```
import UIKit

class MenuLabel: UILabel {

    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        return true
    }

    // MARK: - Init

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    private func commonInit() {
        isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        addGestureRecognizer(
            UILongPressGestureRecognizer(
                target: self,
                action: #selector(handleLongPressed(_:))
            )
        )
    }

    // MARK: - Actions

    internal func handleLongPressed(_ gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        guard let gestureView = gesture.view, let superView = gestureView.superview else {
            return
        }

        let menuController = UIMenuController.shared

        guard !menuController.isMenuVisible, gestureView.canBecomeFirstResponder else {
            return
        }

        gestureView.becomeFirstResponder()

        menuController.menuItems = [
            UIMenuItem(
                title: "Custom Item",
                action: #selector(handleCustomAction(_:))
            ),
            UIMenuItem(
                title: "Copy",
                action: #selector(handleCopyAction(_:))
            )
        ]

        menuController.setTargetRect(gestureView.frame, in: superView)
        menuController.setMenuVisible(true, animated: true)
    }

    internal func handleCustomAction(_ controller: UIMenuController) {
        print("Custom action!")
    }

    internal func handleCopyAction(_ controller: UIMenuController) {
        UIPasteboard.general.string = text ?? ""
    }

}
```

Key things to takeaway from this are:

- making sure the label overrides `canBecomeFirstResponder`
- `isUserInteractionEnabled` set to true
- calling `gestureView.becomeFirstResponder()` in the long press handler

You can add this label to Interface Builder or create it in code.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Looking for one more favour from your side. If my lable text is "Show Label Menu"  and I to set menu on spacific word on which user taps. I want to show menu on word 'Show' and copy that word only into UIPasteboard

Comment: If you want a user to select a word then you should use a non editable UITextView. The functionality is built in and it would be a lot of work to do it yourself.

Comment: I'm doing it with Label and partially succeed and getting words but tap index and word are not matching...