# Referring to programmatically created UI elements

Tags: ios, swift3

I'm creating many UI elements programmatically. Let's say 50 UILabels. 
What is a proper way to access to labels properties? 
Now i'm adding a tag to each label and next search label in [subview] array and get label properties through a 'sender':

```
    func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton) {

        for subview in containerView.subviews {

            if let label = subview as? UILabel, label.tag == sender.tag {
// do stuff
}
}
}
```

Not sure it's most elegant way because there are some problems if we change labels to buttons.

Lets say:

```
func createButton() {
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(origin: ...,
                                        size: ...))

    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    let longTap = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(disableButton(sender:)))
    longTap.minimumPressDuration = 1
    button.addGestureRecognizer(longTap)

    .......
    containerView.addSubview(button)

}
```

And now i can't access to properties via 'sender' in disableButton(sender:) method, because sender is UILongPressGestureRecognizer.

Seems like im doing something wrong if it works for labels but not for buttons. 
Please, guide me in right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I would keep and array with a reference to all of the labels so you don't have to iterate through all of the subviews to find them and keep this in order with the highest z value first.  But if you don't want to do that here is the code that can find you view in one line; its not the most efficient thing in the world but for your number fo views it should be fine.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let first = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50))
    let second = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 25, y: 25, width: 100, height: 50))
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        first.text = "first"
        first.backgroundColor = .blue
        second.text = "second"
        second.backgroundColor = .red
        view.addSubview(first)
        view.addSubview(second)
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(sender:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }
    @objc func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)  { 
        if let label = view.subviews.flatMap({$0 as? UILabel}).last(where: { $0.bounds.contains(sender.location(in: $0))}) {
            print("You pressed: \(label)")
        }
    }
}
```

Note whats going on here:

1. We use flatMap to discard any subviews that are not UIlabels.
2. We use last to find the last item in the array (
   because the top most views are last according to UIView.subviews) where the touch is inside that view's bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Simple add this code when your creating your label

```
yourLbl.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

And use **touchesBegan** method to get your clicked label

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

   let touch = touches.first
    if let lblView = touch?.view
    {
        if lblView.isKind(of: UILabel.self)
        {
            let yourLbl = lblView as! UILabel

            //Access your clicked lable
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: But what about long tap? I got no problems with just touch

Comment: reffer this link for long press [long press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45243947/uilabel-long-press-gesture-for-menu-item-of-uimenucontroller)